# Wordpress full video

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, video

Here is the video in wordpress when you will pause the video you will see the donate button 
How to show this button on full screen?

```
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
<h6>Please make sure to watch the video in its entirety at least once . This will ensure that you will enjoy all the benefits of this powerful therapeutic technique</h6>
[video width="640" height="360" mp4="http://theposturesaver.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Bretching.mp4" id="myVideo" ][/video]

<div class="btd" style="width: 150px; text-align: center; display: none; position: absolute; margin-top: -370px; margin-left: 200px; z-index: 10000;"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" />
<input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="5TKNPWWBH73VL" />
<p style="color:white; font-weight:bold; width:550px; margin-left:-170px; font-size:15px">OUR PROJECT CANNOT BE SUCCESSFUL WITHOUT YOUR HELP, WE ARE HONORED THAT YOU ARE CONSIDERING MAKING A CONTRIBUTION.</p>
<input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/paypal_donate_button/8-2-paypal-donate-button-high-quality-png.png" type="image" />
<img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/paypal_donate_button/8-2-paypal-donate-button-high-quality-png.png" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />
<h6 style="color:white; width:550px; margin-left:-170px;">WHEN YOU ARE GOOD TO OTHERS YOU ARE BEST TO YOURSELF</h6>
</form></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    /*<![CDATA[*/ $(document).ready(function(){
     $('video').on('ended',function(){ $('.btd').css('display','block'); $('video').css('opacity','0'); }); $('video').on('pause',function(){ $('.btd').css('display','block'); $('video').css('opacity','0'); }); $('video').on('play', function() { $('.btd').css('display','none'); $('video').css('opacity','1'); }); 




}); /*]]>*/
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: You have to write more specifications than this - as the question stands now, we have zero to none chance to help you. also It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input, the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Thanks I edit anybody if can help so please :)

Comment: Personally, I don't think I can help you - But I found this fiddle, which adds an overlay to the fullscreen video : you might get some inspiration there : http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/